# Error: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ShellStream'

Tags: c#, ssh

I am using C# and ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application. I am trying to use Renci SSH.NET to connect to remote unix box and execute the unix commands. The code was working fine, and now suddenly I am getting error as - Cannot access a disposed object. I have used the below code

```
public void function1()
{
 SshClient sshclient = new SshClient(hostname, username, pwd);
 sshclient.Connect();
 ShellStream stream = sshclient.CreateShellStream("cms1d", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

 objCatcher.WriteOnlyInfo("whoami", stream);

 objCatcher.WriteOnlyInfo("command 2", stream);

 stream.Dispose();
 sshclient.Disconnect();
 sshclient.Dispose();
}

public void WriteOnlyInfo(string customCMD, ShellStream stream)
 {
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;

    WriteStream(customCMD, writer, stream);
}

private void WriteStream(string cmd, StreamWriter writer, ShellStream stream)
{
   writer.WriteLine(cmd);
   while (stream.Length == 0)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
   }
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

The first command is working and when the code executes the second command, I am getting the error. I have tried removing the RENCI dll and adding it back. Cleaning and re-building the solution. 
The object is disposed only at the end of the function. 
But this has not helped. How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: `StreamWriter` will take ownership of the `Stream` it's passed, and will dispose it when it is disposed. You will need to set the `leaveOpen` constructor parameter to `true`.

Comment: Also, `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable`, and needs to be explicitly disposed. Consider using `using` statements instead of calling `.Dispose()` directly.

Comment: @canton7 Looks like the `StreamWriter` is not disposed though. So we need another explanation. A finalizer perhaps?

Comment: I suspect the stream is empty (not returning any data) and is closing.  Are you getting any exceptions?